# How long does Static / Dynamic analysis take in Intelix?

Tags: sophoslabs-intelix

I am currently testing the Intelix API within my service.

Please could you tell me the average time a static and dynamic analysis will take?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

This is a little hard to say because the time taken for the analysis depends on the sample. Especially with Dynamic analysis, take for example a PE file, as it is detonated some executables will do lots and run for a long time where as others can finish running in seconds.

In my experience static analysis takes 10-20 seconds on average. Where as Dynamic analysis takes a few minutes. However these figures heavily depend on the exact sample that is submitted.

Obviously it is best to build your logic around the advertised maximum time for each analysis. However, when thinking about average times, think static analysis in seconds, dynamic in minutes.